# Show Bootstrap 3 Modal using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am using AngularJS 1.5.0 and Bootstrap 3.3.6.

I am trying to display the [Bootstrap Modal Plugin](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) using AngularJS.
It is easy to display using [Bootstrap JS Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp) 
`$("#myModal").modal()` works with JQuery, but I need to get this working with AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to install the  [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io) which is a Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS. Then you can use the Modal as seen in the Demo [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal)